# android - how to show location on map with XML file

Tags: android, gps

i have an XML file with coordinats location of 3 places.
i want to show these 3 places location in the map.
i have an example of XML file and the map with the locations.
my question is how to do that.
thanks for the help

**XML Example**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><root><LastTrans><Vnumber>2057172</Vnumber><GPSDateTime>2016-05-28T20:45:59.380</GPSDateTime><Latitude>3.1968964e+001</Latitude><Longtitude>3.4819195e+001</Longtitude><IgnitionOn>0</IgnitionOn><Speed>0</Speed><Address>ראשון לציון יהודה שגיא 22</Address><MileCounter>431148</MileCounter></LastTrans><LastTrans><Vnumber>2009072</Vnumber><GPSDateTime>2016-05-28T20:26:59.790</GPSDateTime><Latitude>3.2055622e+001</Latitude><Longtitude>3.4808765e+001</Longtitude><IgnitionOn>0</IgnitionOn><Speed>0</Speed><Address>תל אביב יפו דרך הטייסים 54</Address><MileCounter>279842</MileCounter></LastTrans><LastTrans><Vnumber>5083131</Vnumber><GPSDateTime>2016-05-28T20:36:59.240</GPSDateTime><Latitude>3.2019333e+001</Latitude><Longtitude>3.4943638e+001</Longtitude><IgnitionOn>0</IgnitionOn><Speed>0</Speed><Address>ברקת הזית 15</Address><MileCounter>445131</MileCounter></LastTrans><LastTrans><Vnumber>6308931</Vnumber><GPSDateTime>2016-05-28T20:57:59.130</GPSDateTime><Latitude>3.2025242e+001</Latitude><Longtitude>3.4869194e+001</Longtitude><IgnitionOn>0</IgnitionOn><Speed>0</Speed><Address>אור יהודה 37</Address><MileCounter>221326</MileCounter></LastTrans></root>
```

**Map Example**

[image: this is the map example]

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse xml. Check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) out.

Comment: but i still dont understand where do i save the xml file? how to save an xml file in the project

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the xml first[For your reference](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/).

and just get the latitude and longitude from it and use Google map api and display markers on that specific position.
Refer this link to display marker on coordinates.[Link for google map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker)

You Just need to put your xml file in your resource (res/values/your xml file).
and just parse the data of xml from here.
[This link helps how you to parse the data from a xml file.](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/228215-working-with-resourses/)

**How to save an xml file**

At first you just need to put your local xml file with data into src\main\assets folder and just retrieve data XML file using this code:

```
AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
    try 
    {
        InputStream is = am.open("1001.xml");
        int length = is.available();
        byte[] data = new byte[length];
        is.read(data);
        String demoInput = new String(data).toString();
    }
    catch (IOException e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

All the Best.

Comment: but i still dont understand where do i save the xml file? how to save an xml file in the project

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse xml string which you are getting from response.

[Check here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_xml_parsers.htm)

Comment: but i still dont understand where do i save the xml file? how to save an xml file in the project